# Docker CentOS image does not auto start httpd

Tags: apache, docker, centos, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a simple Docker image with Apache and a PHP program. It works fine if I run

```
docker run -t -i -p 80:80 my/httpd /bin/bash
```

then manually start Apache

```
service httpd start
```

however I cant get httpd to start automatically when running

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 my/httpd
```

Apache will startup then container exists. I have tried a bunch of different `CMD`s in my docker file

```
CMD /etc/init.d/httpd start
CMD ["service" "httpd" "start"]
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/etc/init.d/httpd start"]
ENTRYPOINT /etc/init.d/httpd CMD start
CMD ./start.sh
```

start.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

However every-time docker instance will exist after apache starts

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to run apache (httpd) directly - you should not use init.d script.

Two options:

1. you have to run apache in foreground: `/usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND ...`  (or /usr/sbin/httpd in CentOS)
2. you have to start all services (including apache configured as auto-run) by executing `/sbin/init` as entrypoint.

Comment: Thanks Jiri! 
Using `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd"]` & `CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]` works a treat

Comment: Just FYI, some people also run:   /sbin/some_deamon && tail -f /var/log/foo

Comment: @ØyvindSkaar `&& tail -f ...` is a nice hack but please note that it will exit container at log rotation event, so I would not recommend it for log files like /var/log/apache2/access.log

Comment: Thanks ØyvindSkaar, while Jiri's method was great for httpd, I used your example for a different tigase container. It works well.

Comment: Also with regard to tailing log files; there is likely no logrotate (and no cron to run it), so you're disk would fill with logs. Using CustomLog's piped log feature would be better. Have a look at rotatelogs(8) which comes with httpd

Answer (score 19):

Add this line in the bottom of your `Dockerfile` to run Apache in the foreground on CentOS

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple  Dockerfile to run httpd on centOS

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install httpd -y
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

Commands for building images and running container

Build

```
docker build . -t chttpd:latest
```

Running container using new image

```
docker container run  -d -p 8000:80 chttpd:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end of Dockerfile, insert below command to start httpd

```
# Start httpd 
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

ENTRYPOINT /usr/sbin/httpd -D start && /bin/bash

Comment: Downvote because a crashed httpd wouldn't exit the container and you need to specify stdin on the container to prevent it from immediately exiting. There's several other better answers describing how to run the process in the foreground. And centos has now reach EOL so I doubt you can get this to work with `centos:latest`.