# container exit with code 0 while using docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I have a dockerfile to install httpd. When i run this dockerfile using the command

**docker run -dit  /bin/bash**,

the container is started and it is running in the background. when i perform **docker ps** i could see the container running.

I have created a docker-compose.yml file as below,

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-apache
    image: web:1.0
    container_name: web
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    command: service httpd start
```

i have build this compose file using the

**docker-compose build**.

Once after that i started the containers using

**docker-compose up -d**.

The containers are getting exited. i am not sure how to make the containers run at background.

Also i want to make the services running inside the container. For example i need to run the command like **service httpd start** inside the container and how to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker CentOS image does not auto start httpd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280174/docker-centos-image-does-not-auto-start-httpd)

Answer (score 7):

This is because a Docker container only lives as long as its command runs. 
Your command `service httpd start` will start httpd in the background and then exit. This will terminate httpd and the container.

You will have to run the httpd process directly and in the foreground, see the [official image's start script](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/b13054c7de5c74bbaa6d595dbe38969e6d4f860c/2.2/httpd-foreground):

`httpd -DFOREGROUND`

Answer (score 1):

You can't run docker with -dit options together. -d means to run it in background mode and -ti means an interaction with terminal. So, have to run with -d OR with -ti and not both